# Point System - localStorage

Tags: javascript, jquery, count, local-storage

I'm trying to create a point system that will do different actions after certain points this is my JS:

```
if (localStorage.points222){
  localStorage.points222=Number(localStorage.points222) +5;
}
else{
  localStorage.points222=0;
}

if(localStorage.points222 > 35){
   $('#hi').show(); 
}
else{
   $('#hi').hide();  
}
document.write("Points: " + localStorage.points222 + "");
```

Then I have the HTML that I want to fadeIn after 35 points:

```
<div id="hi" style="display:none;">30!</div>
```

The problem is that the IF:

```
if(localStorage.points222 > 35){
       $('#hi').show(); 
    }
    else{
       $('#hi').hide();  
    }
```

Is not working...

Only this works:

```
 if(localStorage.points222!==35){
       $('#hi').show(); 
    }
    else{
       $('#hi').hide();  
    }
```

But I don't want **#hi** to only show at 35 I need it too show from 35 and Up

Comment: What about `parseInt(localStorage.points222) > 35`?

Comment: @Jared at least in Chromium, js will interpret strings properly for > comparison, but you might be onto something for other browsers.  Also, you might want to go with the canonical `+localStorage.points222`

Comment: @alex c - You mean Chromium as in the OS? (Wondering if that includes Chrome...) What does the `+` do?

Comment: @Jared I mean Chromium the open-source browser/browser base.  i.e. it works in Chrome, RockMelt, Blackbird, and all other Chromium-based browsers.  I assume it generally works in V8, so node probably works as well.  The `+` tries to convert to a number (so `+"14" === 14` and `+"!4" == NaN`.  Anyway, your idea is probably right, as this code seems to work fine when I test it from Chrome's console.

Comment: @alex c - Ah, I see. I haven't seen either form before, but both make sense. Why would `+` be canonical and `parseInt()` not be (if this doesn't get off the path a bit...)?

Comment: Canonical is probably too strong a word; more accurate would be to say the `+` has been the "proper" way to do number conversion in several style guides I've used.  Actually, I've always been a fan of using `parseInt(str)` or `Number(str)` -- I think both are clearer than `+` -- but `+` is a little less verbose.  In my opinion, both are equally good, provided they are used consistently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I bet the problem is that the local storage is coming back as a string, but you're treating it like a number. You need

```
if(Number(localStorage.points222) > 35){
       $('#hi').show(); 
    }
    else{
       $('#hi').hide();  
    }
```

Comment: Don't know about other browsers, but string/number comparison works fine in Chromium.

Comment: @alex that's just Chrome though, what about Firefox, Safari, etc.? And in Chrome it doesn't seem to work for me because it's a string, not a number.

Comment: @Shawn31313 - Have you tried using the `console` to check the variable?

Comment: @Nathan open up the Chrome inspector (or a node shell), type "14" < 15  returns true.  Type "14" < 13 returns false.  It certainly may be different for Firefox or Safari as they use different js engines, but I'm fairly sure number/string comparison should generally work as per js standard.  It is definitely in the Firefox docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators.

Comment: @Shawn31313 - Usually something like console.log(localStorage.points222). Read more here: http://code.google.com/chrome/devtools/docs/console.html (*Note, I am a Firebug aficionado, and don't use Chrome console that often.*)

Comment: Chrome has developer tools that are just as good as firebug :P

Comment: @Joseph - I didn't say or mean to imply otherwise, I'm just not an expert. ;) Consult the docs. It's a moot point anyways since the OP is using Chrome.

Comment: @Jared Farrish I apologize if I came across as saying you were implying otherwise. :(  I only meant that all of the core features of firebug are also in Chrome and can be easily accessed.  For the record, my favorite set of developer tools happens to be Opera's.  (Especially the element position guidelines O_O).  Sorry again for the poor wording on my part.

Comment: @Joseph - No worries. Opera has always had a strong product, and Firebug was awesome first (long, *long* time user), but Chrome (or Chromium) will probably outlive us all.